# TableView inside tableview cell swift 3

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, swift3, height

I'm tring to display tableView inside tableview cell while both parent and child tableview have dynamic cell height.

First problem is not all cells show child tableView.
In cells that show childTableView, childTableView height is not right.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var items = ["Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front !"

    ,"Consider, though, that Swift us a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!"  ,"ccc", "ddd","Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!", "Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!","fff", "Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!","hhhh","Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!","jjj", "Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!", "Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!Consider, though, that Swift uses value types almost exclusively, which is mind-boggling when you consider that the situation in Objective-C is completely the reverse.As a code architect under the new Swift paradigm, you need to doa bit of up-front planning as to how your data will be used. You can solve almost any situation witheither value types or reference types — but using them incorrectly could result in tons of bugs and confusing cde.In all cases, common sense and a willingness to change your architecture when new requirements come up is the best approach.Challenge yourself to follow the Swift model; you just might turn out some nicer code than you originally thought!"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpTableView();
}

func setUpTableView(){
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MCQCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MCQCell");
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
}   

  extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(tableView == self.tableView){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MCQCell", for:indexPath) as! MCQCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.lblTxt.text = items[row];
        cell.tableView.tag = row;
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self;
        cell.tableView.delegate = self;
        cell.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60;
        cell.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell;
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChoiceCell", for:indexPath) as! ChoiceCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.lblTxt.text = items[row];
        return cell;
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(tableView == self.tableView){
        return items.count;
    }else{
        return 5;
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
}
```

and inside Parent tableview cell I just register childTableView cell and reloading tableview

```
  override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize,
                             withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority,
                             verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize{

    tableView.reloadData()
    let size = CGSize(width: targetSize.width,
                      height: tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.contentSize.height)
    return size

}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to give height constraint to your child table view

Comment: But I don't want this table view to be scrollable inside its parent cell I need it to take the full content size of its child cells..

Comment: yes i am answering for the same when you reload table you can set heightConstranint.constant = tableview.contentsize.height

Comment: yes I did that, and the parent table view cell takes tableview height, but not the whole cell height

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
-> Disable childtableview scrolling.        

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                return CGFloat((ChildTableviewCellItem.count) * Height_childtableviewcell+Height_MainTableviewcell)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the size of the child table view cells they also have dynamic  height